# Javascript won't search updated HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I've been doing tiny little projects to try to learn Javascript. When I was playing with Kahoot I noticed that even though it should be a different color ~25% of the time, it seems to be red the majority of the time.

I'm trying to make javascript code to put into the console that lets me automatically always choose red and then it records whether it was correct or incorrect.

To click red, I can do `var red = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];` then `red.click()`, and to check if it's right or wrong I can do

```
if ((document.documentElement.innerText).indexOf('Incorrect') > -1) {
            alert('Incorrect');
        } else if ((document.documentElement.innerText).indexOf("Correct") > -1) {
            alert('Correct');
        }
```

This works... sometimes. I think I know the problem but I don't know how to fix it. The button red will disappear to display whether it was correct or incorrect, then it will pop back up.

Normally I can set the variable red, and it works, but the next time the button pops up and I set the variable again it says `undefined`. In order to fix this, I need to use inspect element to press "Edit HTML" then press Enter.

I think this helps because when it says `undefined` it's looking through an older version of the HTML, the one where the button is hidden, and when I edit the html it updates the html that the javascript is searching.

Edit: I'm bad at explaining, so here's a video on my problem: https://youtu.be/9WaIOPRny28

Comment: You need to look into a lot of things. The code you posted does not really say anything about the context. When/how does your button's click event work, for example? Please post a fiddle that you have tried.

Comment: @Gogol StackOverflow snippets is the preferred way to present runnable code, please do not suggest external code presentation.

Comment: insufficient information/code regarding the issue you desribed, how can we help ?? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @connexo I get the point :) I generalized the term `fiddle`. SOF snippet it is ;)

Comment: I'm not great at explaining things, I hope this video I made helps: https://youtu.be/9WaIOPRny28

Comment: ^^ that's not a good way of posting the mcve. Do you expect everyone to type the code you typed in your console, in their console? :) Plus, I do not see the html on which your code is working. If you can't post a mcve, atleast post the html and JS code over here. I plus one'd your question because I want you to become a contributing member over here. Let's see what you post now ;)

Comment: [Here is the HTML I'm working with](https://pastebin.com/raw/vip6wnuE), when the screen changes the button becomes disabled, and currently all I'm trying to do is find the button using `document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];` in the console

Comment: @Andrew The HTML is obviously not enough...I'm sure you would get help, if you just provided a working jsfiddle or jsbin example.